# You are not allowed to edit this post. Even I have admin rights wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I m getting this error   "You are not allowed to edit this post." even i m trying to add images from slider or any posting things not working for me on my localhost Thanks if you want any clearance ask me Thank you btw i m using wordpress 4.3.1 version

Comment: Have you tried:
- resetting the plugins folder by FTP or phpMyAdmin.
- switching to the Twenty Ten theme to rule out any theme-specific problems.

Comment: There must have been something you've done between the point of installing Wordpress, to now. If you create a new Administrator user, and login using that.. does that solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for comment @NooBskie i have tried both....  I used twenty ten its working fine like posting even my earlier them also its working for posting but when i m trying to  submit any image it wont take (logo, header images working fine) problem in slider images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer the problem is in new version of my theme slider type folder there is slider.php file I commented `/*'capabilities' => array (
            'manage_terms' => 'administrator',
            'edit_terms' => 'administrator',
            'delete_terms' => 'administrator',
            'assign_terms' => 'administrator', 'editor'
            ), */` its worked for me ...